# How to manipulate existing group elements with Snap.svg

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

We have an existing svg-document in witch we want to replace a group-element with a new one. Is it possible to do with Snap.svg?

```
var oldGroup = Snap.select("[id='" + oldGroupId + "']");

oldGroup.outerSVG(newGroup); //This is what I want to do but outerSVG is readonly
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't relace an element using just outerSVG. You haven't included enough information to give a complete correct answer, as we can't see what the existing elements, but it may be something like..

```
var parent = oldGroup.parent();
oldGroup.remove();
parent.add( newGroup )
```

This would depend on what 'newGroup' is. If its a DOM element, I think it would work. If its just some SVG Markup, you would probably need to do something like

```
parent.add( Snap.parse( newGroup ) );
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! Works in both Chrome and IE 9.

Comment: This might affect drawing order, but that's not an issue right now.

Comment: If it does, you could possibly use element.after()/before() to append the new element to the correct place before removing the old one maybe.